# Android: String replace("<\" , "<") returns error

Tags: android, string, replace

I need to replace all the `<\` symbols with `<` in a HTML String retrieved using JSON.
Apparently, 
`String correctText = TEXT.replace("<\" , "<");`
cannot be performed because the first expression is recognized as an exit statement instead of a Char sequence.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
String correctText = TEXT.replace("<\\" , "<");
```

Comment: ... because String.replace uses regular expressions.

Comment: @Vyger No it doesn't. Backslash is just a special char in Java string literals.

Comment: @Iaalto: So, also "dot" is `just a special char in Java literals`, because, I had to match "." with "\." in my code... no, wait, I used replaceAll ;)